# rewrite all pages /en/XXX to /en

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

It's been a while since I've been busting my head to do a htaccess rewrite.
I would like to redirect all the pages from example.com/en/XXX to example.com/en.
I'm doing either redirection loops or errors 500.

Is it possible to help me to find the right formula?

I tried RewriteRule `^en/(.+)$ /en/ L,QSA`
also this RewriteRule `^/en\/.*$ http://example.com/en/$1 [R=permanent,L]`

Do you also know good links to learn htaccess and rewrite?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `RewriteRule ^en/.+$ en/ [L,QSA]` should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a condition to stop Looping, could you please try following once, base on your shown samples only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/.*/?$ [NC] [L]
RewriteRule ^(en)/.*$ http://example.com/$1 [NC,L]
```

Merci RaVinder pour ton aide ! <3

Comment: Thank you very much. It works pretty well for links in **example.com/en/XXX ** but not for links in example.com/en/XXX.(html/php)

Comment: @Pipinlink, Please give an sample example of url which is not working here and I will edit the rules then.

Comment: @Pipinlink, Ok, I have changed the Rules now, could you please check it now and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: the site is in error 500. 
I commented the line RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/.*(\.html|\.php)/?$ [L] *The site is up again

Comment: @Pipinlink, could you please try edited Rules, I am yet to test it, please check them once and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: you are a GENIUS! Thank you very much. 
Would you know a good tutorial to learn rewrite? 
ps: The last Rewrite is missing an R.

Comment: @Pipinlink, your welcome and thank you for nice words :) I learnt/learning from documentation of apache.

Comment: @Pipinlink, you could give through profile of legend users anubhava, Mr. White in SO too, they are GURUs of htaccess I know little only :)